# NextAuth with MongoDB Adapter and CredentialsProvider - Login Fails

Tags: mongodb, next.js, next-auth

#### Description

I'm using NextAuth in my application with the MongoDB adapter and CredentialsProvider for username and password authentication. Unfortunately, the login fails when I enable the MongoDB adapter, while it works without the adapter.

#### Issue

When using the MongoDB adapter in my NextAuth configuration with CredentialsProvider, the login no longer works. The authorize handler of the CredentialsProvider seems to have issues with database access.

#### Code Sample

```js
// auth.js

import mongoose from "mongoose";
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { User } from "@/app/models/User";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import { MongoDBAdapter } from "@auth/mongodb-adapter";
import clientPromise from "@/libs/mongoConnect";

export const authOptions = {
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        }),
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: "credentials",
            id: "credentials",
            credentials: {
                username: {
                    label: "Email",
                    type: "email",
                    placeholder: "test@example.com",
                },
                password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
            },
            async authorize(credentials, req) {
                const email = credentials?.email;
                const password = credentials?.password;

                mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL);
                const user = await User.findOne({ email });
                const passwordOk = user && bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);

                if (passwordOk) {
                    return user;
                }

                return null;
            },
        }),
    ],
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

```js
// This approach is taken from https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-mongodb
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";

if (!process.env.MONGO_URL) { //MONGO_URL is the label in my .env file
    throw new Error('Invalid/Missing environment variable: "MONGODB_URI"');
}

const uri = process.env.MONGO_URL;
const options = {};

let client;
let clientPromise;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
    // In development mode, use a global variable so that the value
    // is preserved across module reloads caused by HMR (Hot Module Replacement).
    if (!global._mongoClientPromise) {
        client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
        global._mongoClientPromise = client.connect();
    }
    clientPromise = global._mongoClientPromise;
} else {
    // In production mode, it's best to not use a global variable.
    client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
    clientPromise = client.connect();
}

// Export a module-scoped MongoClient promise. By doing this in a
// separate module, the client can be shared across functions.
export default clientPromise;
```

### Error Message

Login fails, and I receive an unexpected server error message. The authorize handler of the CredentialsProvider seems to have an issue with database access.

#### What I've Tried

- I double-checked my database connection and it works when the MongoDB adapter is disabled.
- I've tried different implementations for the MongoDB adapter to ensure proper database access.

#### Expected Outcome

A working configuration for NextAuth with the MongoDB adapter and CredentialsProvider so that I can successfully authenticate users using username and password.

**Thanks in advance for your help!**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i tried this and worked!

add this

session: {
// Set it as jwt instead of database
strategy: "jwt",
},

as note that if you want to persist the credentials session, you need to set session.strategy as 'jwt'. Credentials provider does not persist the session in the database.

The Credentials provider can only be used if JSON Web Tokens are enabled for sessions. Users authenticated with the Credentials provider are not persisted in the database.
https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/providers/credentials

so ur code must be like this

```
secret: process.env.SECRET,
adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),
session: {
    // Set it as jwt instead of database
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        }),
```